# English Translation of French Verseurs

Tags: vector-spaces

Trying to read Lamaitres 1948 paper on Quaternions, in reply to Klein's Verlangen program, but can not find a translation of term Verseurs, which is even a section heading:

"Un quaternion dont la norme est egale a un s'apelle un verseur, Le produit de deux verseurs est un verseur."

Anyone know what verseur translates to?

Comment: Verlangen program?

Comment: Well, a verseur is a quaternion whose norm is $1$, do we really need to know more?

Comment: [Echoing @ChristianRemling's comment...]

Comment: So, the English translation is "versor".  Or maybe the other way around? "versor" in English was translated to "verseur" in French.

Comment: Klein's program was published in **Erlangen**, maybe inspired by "ein großes Verlangen" to push things further...

Answer (score 6):

See the enlightening [Wikipeda article on versors](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Versor) (which include etymology).

Comment: Very good... but/and "wikiwand.com", not "wikipedia.org" FWIW.

Comment: @paulgarrett it's a nicer front end.

Comment: Ah, indeed, I didn't know! :)